# Expression of subset in a proposition

Tags: logic

$A \subseteq B$

Can we use this in a proposition? 
For instance, if A is a subset of B, then x belongs to B and blah blah.

Which proposition is good to use from the below?

($A \subseteq B) \Rightarrow (x \in B,$ blah blah)

or

$((x \in A) \Rightarrow x \in B) \Rightarrow (x \in$ B, blah blah)

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking, but $x \in A$ certainly implies $x \in B$ if $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not sure if I can use $A \subseteq B$ in a proposition or not.. new to logic sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are allowed to write. One way would be, considering $ \land$ as the logical "and" operator, as:

$$((x \in A) \land (A \subseteq B)) \implies (x \in B),$$

or translating $A\subseteq B$ as $(\forall x \,( (x \in A) \implies (x \in B))),$ it would be

$$((x \in A) \land (\forall x \, (x \in A) \implies (x \in B))) \implies (x \in B)  $$

Comment: This is very problematic because of the assumption/requirement  that $x\in A$.  Perhaps $A=\varnothing?$  For all sets $B$, $\varnothing \subseteq B$

Answer (score 0):

$A\subseteq B$, by definition, means exactly that $$\forall x\big((x \in A)\rightarrow (x\in B)\big)$$ period.

Alternatively $$(A\subseteq B) \iff\forall x\big(( x\in A) \rightarrow  (x \in B)\big)$$